# Fixed marker on google maps for ios

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, fixed, drag

I am using google maps SDK for ios. I want to make a marker fixed in the center of the screen, so when user drags the map, the marker does not move and stays in the center. I am also trying to read the coordinate of the center after the drag. Any input would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I would rather display view on top of GMSMapView (do not use markers for that). Since you have screen position for map view, that should be easy to place your view in correct position.

To get coordinates you can use `mapView.projection.coordinateForPoint`

Documentation is [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_projection#a4e912bf5b8778dec702e025ea2036d49)

To know that drag is finished, make you view controller (or any other object) delegate of map view (`GMSMapViewDelegate`) and implement `mapView:idleAtCameraPosition:` method.

Docs are [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/protocol_g_m_s_map_view_delegate-p#af1129dee4fcef90292d96c0aa7764ced)

Comment: Thanks Piotr. I have difficulty displaying view on top of GMSMapView. I tried to use 'insertSubview' and 'addSubview', but as long as I set 'self.view = _mapView;', the marker view does not show up on top.

Comment: first add the marker view and then `yourMapView.bringSubviewToFront(view: yourMarkerView)` @Yini

Answer (score 6):

Create outlet of GMSMapView and attached Image at the center of the map and search bar at the top to present the location name.

**Drag the map on Device, which will trigger 2 delegate method of GMSMapViewDelegate.**

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didChange position: GMSCameraPosition) 
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, idleAt position: GMSCameraPosition)
```

> ```
>     /**
>      * Called repeatedly during any animations or gestures on the map (or once, if the camera is
>      * explicitly set). This may not be called for all intermediate camera positions. It is always
>      * called for the final position of an animation or gesture.
>      */
>     func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didChange position: GMSCameraPosition) {
>       print("didchange")>             > 
>        returnPostionOfMapView(mapView: mapView)
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * Called when the map becomes idle, after any outstanding gestures or animations have completed (or
>      * after the camera has been explicitly set).
>      */
>     func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, idleAt position: GMSCameraPosition) {
>         print("idleAt")
>
>         //called when the map is idle
>         returnPostionOfMapView(mapView: mapView)
>
>     }
>
>     //Convert the location position to address 
>     func returnPostionOfMapView(mapView:GMSMapView){
>         let geocoder = GMSGeocoder()
>         let latitute = mapView.camera.target.latitude
>         let longitude = mapView.camera.target.longitude
>         let position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitute, longitude)
>         geocoder.reverseGeocodeCoordinate(position) { response , error in
>             if error != nil {
>                 print("GMSReverseGeocode Error: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
>             }else {
>                 let result = response?.results()?.first
>                 let address = result?.lines?.reduce("") { $0 == "" ? $1 : $0 + ", " + $1 }
>                 self.searchBar.text = address
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

[image]

[Github Demo Project](https://github.com/shrawan2015/Application/tree/master/GoogleMapExample)

Comment: what is region for using location manager delegate in that case